# Java String treatment with splitting

Tags: java, string

I need your help. I have a string with value `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"`.
What I want to do is take once first value (`"1"`) only (`substring (0, 1)` for example) and then do a loop with the rest of values except the first value that I already take.

Maybe I have to create another String variable and set the values without first value to the second String variable and then create a loop? How to do that?

Comment: Do *what* inside the loop? What splitting have you done? Why use `subString(...)` if you plan on using `String#split(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function.

```
String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"; //Here your String

String[] array = numbers.split(","); //Here you divide the String taking as reference the ,

String number = array[0] //You will get the number 1
```

If you want to take the rest of the elements:

```
for(i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    System.out.println(array[i]);
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: Ok, thanks, done. The only thing I cant understand why so negative vote on my question. Not everybody could be guru in one day :) Anyway, thanks to all for the help.

Comment: @user2137580 I didn't downvote your question, I'm also not a guru of Java (hopefully) and I understand this kind of questions (I was also a beginner and now I have a bit experience) but I think they downvote you because there are a lot of questions that are related with `split` function here in SO. I guess.

Comment: I'm don't tell that it is you, just it was a strange )) maybe here is a lots of similar questions, but my question was about how to do the whole process, not how to split. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would probably be to use [`String#split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
String[] parts = str.split(",");

// Save the first part
String firstPart = parts[0];

// Iterate over the others:
for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println (parts[i]); // Or do something useful with it
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It is the same answer as below and very useful. Many thanks to all.